# ionic cordova platform add android Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

any help with  ionic cordova platform add android: 
when i run this commend i found this error!!

> ionic cordova platform add android

[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.1.1

```
    Adding android project...
    Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
            Path: platforms\android
            Package: io.ionic.starter
            Name: ionicFirebase
            Activity: MainActivity
            Android target: android-27
    Android project created with cordova-android@7.1.4
    Android Studio project detected
    Android Studio project detected
    Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png
```

and when i run platform ls i am found android@7.1.4 in install platform but on ionic project folder no create any directory to platforms install also when i remove resources/android directory manually and run ionic cordova resources directory don't create again??

i am try run this commend after and before remove platform same the following error:

> ionic cordova resource

√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

[ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add

and same error when rm android and run again ionic cordova resources and when run ionic cordova resources and add platform again same error can't find path!! I can't find any solution to my problem and try cordova v7.0.1 and latest and v6.3.1 every version i found the same error  and this my ionic info

> ionic info

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.16.0
npm               : 4.6.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this folder with your resource folder: [resource](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1saufgIvkEGUgN_HvNrmB2oaWnClTRTUB)

and run this cmd again: **ionic cordova platform add android**

Comment: × Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.1.1

        Adding android project...
        Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
                Path: platforms\android
                Activity: MainActivity
                Android target: android-27
        Android project created with cordova-android@7.1.4
        Android Studio project detected
        Android Studio project detected
        Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Answer (score 0):

Generate resources using the command `ionic cordova resources` and try again.